# ModalDialog in wicket 9 doesnt work properly

Tags: java, wicket

I'm using Modal Dialog in wicket 9 because the old Modal Window class got deprecated and I'm having some issues with it. In wicket 9 documentation there is no example with ModalDialog. I dont know if I'm using it wrong or it has some bugs

```java
public class MainPanel extends Panel {

    private final ModalDialog modalDialog;

    public MainPanel(String id, IModel<String> headingIdx, IModel<String> collapseIdx) {
        super(id);
        setOutputMarkupId(true);
        modalDialog = new ModalDialog("modalWindow");

        add(new AjaxLink<Void>("showModalDialog") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                modalDialog.setContent(new ModalPanel("content", MainPanel.this){
                    @Override
                    protected void close(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        modalDialog.close(target);
                    }
                });
                modalDialog.open(target);
            }
        });
        add(modalDialog);
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<wicket:panel>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-right">
            <a wicket:id="showDeleteDialog" class="btn fa fa-trash p24-2x deleteTrashIcon"></a>
        </div>
    <div wicket:id="modalWindow" class="modalDialog"></div>
</wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

```java
public abstract class ModalPanel extends Panel {
    public ModalPanel(String id, Panel caller) {
        super(id);
        setOutputMarkupId(true);

        add(new AjaxLink<Void>("cancelBtn") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                close(target);
            }
        });
    }

    protected abstract void close(AjaxRequestTarget target);
}
```

The problem is that after modal dialog was opened, it doesnt behave like modal dialog.

Did someone use ModalDialog, may be you can share your experience if it does work for you ?

Comment: Have you added a theme to your dialog? See `org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.modal.theme.DefaultTheme`. I will update the documentation ASAP.

Comment: @svenmeier yes it was missing and it was one of the problem. thanks for updating documentation

Comment: Good replacement but it wouldn't have hurt to provide Baseclasses that already implement closebutton and moving the Modal around (like in ModalWindow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks OK to me!

You can compare it against the example:

- code: https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/5c63eb59510d954f52150f069690a528849cd803/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/ajax/builtin/modal/ModalDialogPage.java
- demo: https://examples9x.wicket.apache.org/ajax/modal-dialog

Comment: is it necessary to have modal dialog inside wicket fragment ? or can I use it inside ```wicket:panel``` ?

Comment: Panel and Fragment are interchangeable. Fragments are inlined panels.

Comment: the modal window almost works as it should work but somehow closing modal through button click doesn't work ? what can it be ?

Answer (score 4):

If you combine the `ModalDialog` with Bootstrap, you may have a clash between the `modal-dialog` class used by the Wicket `ModalDialog` HTML template and the Bootstrap class of the same name. In particular, the Bootstrap `modal-dialog` class turns off pointer events causing clicks in the modal dialog to have no effect.

To fix this, you can add the Bootstrap `modal-content` to the Wicket `ModalDialog` content element:

```
add(new AjaxLink<Void>("showModalDialog") {
  @Override
  public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    Panel content = new MyContentPanel("content");
    content.add(AttributeModifier.append("class", "modal-content"));
    modalDialog.open(content, target);
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you can add the `modal-content` class to root node of the HTML template of the Panel you use for the modal dialog's content.